# Executing multiple steps to handle a purchase using currying

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, e-commerce

Is doing something like this utilizing currying in a practical sense?

```
function processOneClickPurchase(item) {
    let context = { step: 0 }

    let addItemToCart = item => {
        let cart = getSession().cart
        cart.items.push(item)
        log('Cart items', cart.items)
        return cart
    }

    ...

    let purchase = generate([
        addItemToCart,
        makePurchase,
        processBilling,
        setupShipping,
        sendPurchaseAndShippingNotification,
    ], null, cleanup)

    return purchase(item)

    function generate(steps, before, after) {
        const takeStep = (incoming, outgoing) => {
            let message = {
                step: ++context.step,
                incoming: incoming,
                outgoing: outgoing
            };

            log('step #'+(context.step), message)

            return outgoing
        }
        const walk = value => {
            return steps.reduce((from, to) => {
                return takeStep(from, to(from))
            }, value)
        }

        (before && steps.push(before)) + (after && steps.push(after))

        return function invoke(state) {
            const hasItems = Array.isArray(state) || !(state = [state])
            const processed = state.map(walk)
            return hasItems ? processed : processed[0]
        }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7mdak6z/25/

I realize there's algebra going on with currying and maybe this is nonsensical, so we're not talking rigid math concepts. However, it seems to me this pattern is rudimentary and it feels like an application of currying over an input to achieve an output. `takeStep()` almost seems like a monad, etc.

I think it would definitely start to sound like a fit if the methods passed to `generate()` simply modified the stream, and perhaps the `takeStep()` function handled side-effects.

Comment: Currying is converting a function taking `n` arguments into series of `n-1` functions each taking 1 argument. For example, currying `foo = (a, b, c) => ...` would be `foo = a => b => c => ...`. Maybe you could clarify to which function do you refer to.

Comment: What does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question, as per the [ask] guidelines. Note that there is a `return purchase(item)` that doesn't make sense since it's not within a function — please ensure that you have included enough code for the question to make sense.

Comment: @morbusg I use `steps` instead of `arguments` for the `n` series of functions, and `invoke()` is being called over the series of functions.

Answer (score 1):

I take it here that you mean “algebra” to mean [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and by extension, [combinatory logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic).

The `takeStep` function is essentially (disregarding side-effects): $$
\lambda ab.b
$$ in lambda calculus, or in JS in terms of identity (using Haskell Curry’s combinator naming):

```
I = a => a
K = a => b => a
KI = K(I)
```

So as the `takeStep` function is simply disregarding the first argument, and the `walk` function calling the second argument with the previous (/initial) value there and then, I’m wondering if you would really be after the `B`-combinator $$
   \lambda fga.f(ga)
$$ (or, as JS: `B = f => g => a => f(g(a))`, often named `compose`) with possibly the `C`-combinator $$
   \lambda fab.fba
$$ (`C = f => a => b => f(b)(a)`) for reversing the arguments (often named `pipe` or `sequence` for `f => g => a => g(f(a))`).

(I’m not sure if the commutativity of the functions or JS evaluation strategy plays a role here.)

Regarding currying, I wonder if you were thinking of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) instead.

Comment: That's interesting, the compose part; my initial desire was to create a piped procedural that allowed an array of functional modifiers to be applied. The `takeStep()` is essentially a bridge observing both, mainly to keep the functions pure (saving to a store would be in the `takeStep()` method). I'll have to read through this a few times to get it, thank you for the response.

Comment: A cleaner, updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/f7mdak6z/42/ `generate()` is now `coalesce()` at the bottom.